# Largest domain for the function $f =\sqrt{xy}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Consider the function $f =\sqrt{xy}$? What is the largest domain for the function?

My first instinct was that $x$ and $y$ both be positive reals. But this is not the largest since we have not accounted for both negative ones. So I believe the answer should be $(\mathbb{R}^+, \mathbb{R}^+) \cup (\mathbb{R}^-, \mathbb{R}^-)$. Is this correct?

Is my way of describing the solution using symbols correct?

Comment: Do R+ and R- include 0?  Should your domain?

Comment: @RossMillikan yeah I forgot about 0,0. So there will be another set containing that and the union of these three sets. Correct?

Comment: Isn't the question rather ill-formed as it stands? Are we assuming the function is from $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$? If so then I agree with the answers below - otherwise it might be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The largest domain, of course, is 
$$
\left\{ (x,y) \mid xy \geq 0 \right\}.
$$
Therefore you are right, *provided that you do not forget the coordinate axes*.

**Beware:** your notation is rather old-fashioned. We write $\mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{R}^{+}$ instead of $(\mathbb{R}^{+},\mathbb{R}^+)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. From $xy\geq 0$ we have:

$x\leq 0$

$y\leq 0$

And

$x\geq 0$

$y\geq 0$

i.e. The first and third quadrants of the Cartesian plane.